# parse references in latex auxiliary file with python

Tags: python, parsing, latex

If you compile a latex file containing labels, the auxiliary file will contain the string associated with every labels.

For example, from the following latex source

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  e^{i\pi} = - 1
  \label{myequation}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

after compiling a `.aux` file is generated, containing:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{myequation}{{1}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

From this file one can see that the equation referenced with `myequation` has label "1".

I am looking for a python class that parses the `.aux` files and generates a dictionary with the correspondence label_name->string.

Is there a python module or parser that does that?

**Additional information**

The reason why I need this is the following. I have 2 latex source files, let's say file1.tex and file2.tex. file2.tex contains references to equations/tables/etc which are present only in file1.tex.
Since the actual string associated to every label in file1.tex is dynamically generated at compile time, my idea would be to

1. compile file1.tex
2. extract the correspondence label->string
3. substitute `\ref{somelabel}` with the actual string in file2.tex with a parser
4. compile file2.tex

Step 3 is easily done, for example, using `sed`. Step 2 is perhaps more cumbersome.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background information what you are trying to do with this information? Maybe there are already tools to tackle this.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz see edited post

Comment: The best way to parse LaTeX is LaTeX itself. So perhaps you can include file1.aux from file2.tex... in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the labels from the other document with the `xr` package (or `xr-hyper` if you're using hyperref):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr}

\externaldocument{file1}

\begin{document}

test \ref{myequation}

\end{document}
```

[image]